# balancing Server side and Client side code on a large website

Tags: php, javascript, web, client-side, server-side

Let's suppose I am programming Facebook (which i'm not), or some other site that involves heavy traffic.

**Our general Layout is:**

1. All CSS is in external files
2. 99% of JS is in external files
3. The back bone of the websites HTML is generated by a PHP/MySQL backend.
4. JS functions to generate the DOM of parts that commonly change.
5. Our server has an inplace API that returns JSON objects that are fed to our DOM builders (JS functions), which take an JSON object array of lets say, a list of friends, then generated ALL the html used for displaying a list of friends, or events, etc.

**Question**

6. Is this reasonable?
7. Is it common practice to have dedicated JS functions to build the DOM as I have mentioned?
8. Is this scalable? Is JS too slow? (btw, we use JQuery almost exclusively)

I know that it tremendously lowers bandwidth and server load, as the server is no longer iterating through a list of friends (of which it also queried for via MySQL) and generating all the HTML, but instead making a query and returning a small JSON object. which seems ok to me, but I would like a 2nd/3rd/4th/... opinion.

Thanks alot!

Let me know if I am missing any critical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your layout is pretty good, but I would still advice you to read [YAHOO! Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). It summarizes it better(**very good read** in my opinion) than I could do.

I think the three most important things facebook does to achieve it's scale:

1. **CACHING** => [Memcached](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=39391378919). This one is really important. You should remember that doing disk IO is slow compared to MEMORY(disk 5ms / memory 40-80ns according to my [book](http://iiusatech.com/murdocca/CAO/)). Facebook has almost all the active data in memory. [These old slides](http://www.scribd.com/doc/4069180/Caching-Performance-Lessons-from-Facebook) say they have more than 5TB in memory. This is going to be way more by now!
2. **HIPHOP** => https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/
3. **OFFLINE PROCESSING** => Use a message queue like for example [redis](http://redis.io), [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/), [gearman](http://gearman.org/) just to name a few.

Some other interesting links:

- http://sizzo.org/wp/talks
- http://www.facebook.com/pages/Scalable-web-architectures/310457196919?v=wall

Answer (score 1):

Given that JS engines are being constantly developed towards improved performance, I think it's a pretty good design. We will be seeing it more and more often as HTML5 & Co gains popularity.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I'm moving towards. I'm pretty happy with it. JS is certainly not too slow. You'll want a good JS templating system. [Trimpath JS Templates](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates) is my favorite of those I've tried.

Comment: Let me know how you make out and what sort of resources you come up with. I've collected and built a nice bunch of tools which I feel really comfortable with. One day I'll document/share them all, I hope.

Comment: Will do. yeah i'm in the process of finding that nice set of tools as well as a nice working scalable design. seems like a never ending process. :P